# linking multiple existing symbols to a single class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created a stage in Flash with several different symbols that I want to link to a single class I have created.

For example I created different symbols with the instance name grid1, 2, 3, etc... and I want them all to link to the class gridButton that I created.

This might be an obvious question, but I'm somewhat new to flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols grid 1,2,3... inherit the class gridButton.

Using IDE, something like this :

[image]

---

Using AS3, like this :

```
public class grid1 extends gridButton { ...
```

Comment: I tried doing that, but for some reason it's been giving me an error saying: `The class [] must subclass 'flash.display.MovieClip' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type.`, any idea?

Comment: yes, set the base class to `'flash.display.MovieClip'` & class to gridButton instead...